# How to convert the simple.JSONArray to normal JSONArray in Java

Tags: java, json, simplejson

I am writing a JAVA program to read the JSON file data and do some processing.
For reading the JSON file data from my Class path resources folder I am using the following code:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

String filePath = "src/main/resources/SampleRequest.json";
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
Object object = parser.parse(new FileReader(filePath));
JSONArray inputjsonArr = (JSONArray) object;
```

As we can see I am using the `import org.json.simple.JSONArray` to read and get the data. Instead of that, I tried using the normal JSONArray import directly `import org.json.JSONArray;` then I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray
```

I wanted to know if it's possible to convert the `simple.JSONArray` to normal `JSONArray`. Or is it possible for me to read the data from the JSON file using the direct `import org.json.JSONArray;` so that I do not have to deal with this conversion at all.

Comment: Aren't those two totally different, separate libraries? Why would you convert between them?

Comment: Actually, for further processing, I would like to use the methods from `import org.json.JSONArray;` such as `getString` etc. Also, my other parts of the program is already using the org.json.JSONArray so I would like to use the same for whole thing. Only for reading the `JSON FILE` i found this approach and I used this. But after implementing the whole thing I realized that I need to completely use the different methods and classes to get and process the data within the JSONObject of this JSONArray so I thought if there is a way to convert then I can convert and proceed with old approach.

Comment: You should really only use one library. Even so the classes are named identical or similar they have NOTHING in common. You cannot cast between them. Basically the only way to convert between them is to convert to json and then parse the json again at which point you can just leave the first library out of the picture and only use the second to the initial parsing and manipulation or whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: *"normal JSONArray"* `org.json.simple` and `org.json` are just **two different JSON libraries** for Java, there is nothing that makes `org.json` more "normal" than `org.json.simple`. If you need to call code that needs the data as `org.json` classes, you should stick with that, and parse the JSON file with `org.json`, not `org.json.simple`. Mixing two different (competing) JSON libraries is just weird, and entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.json.simple` and `org.json` are different and incompatible libraries.

The use of `org.json.simple` shouldn't be recommended as it returns all of its values as an `Object`, whereas `org.json` allows to dictate what `type` to return.

The solution is not to use the `org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser` (delete all of the `org.json.simple` imports) but to read the String from the relevant file and pass that to the `org.json.JSONArray` directly, like so:

```
String json = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File( "src/main/resources/SampleRequest.json"), "UTF-8" );
JSONArray array = new JSONArray(json);
```

As you can see, I like to use the `FileUtils` from the following package for simplicity's sake, so add this dependency:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.0</version>
</dependency>
```